# Is there a good voice recording library for Android?

Tags: android, audio, recording

I'm looking for something like Android's built-in camera app, just for audio recording.
If possible, I would like to start an Activity, and retrieve back an URL for the file in which audio data has been saved. No matter if it works somehow else, but it should be similarly simple.
I've tried to google it, but found nothing.
Is there a library like this?

Answer (score 7):

Recording audio is really not that hard to accomplish, so you shouldn't need any libraries. Refer to [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) for audio recording example. Also, check out [this library](https://github.com/steelkiwi/AndroidRecording).